# Set method of Arraylist

Tags: java

why set method of Arraylist doesnt throw a Concurrentmodificationexception when values are actually being changed?

If you try to modify the list using remove method while iterating, it throws an error. I understand it wont happen if Iterator of that class is used while removing. But the set method wont throw any error even when iterator is not used. why?

Edit : I am not sure if its a duplicate question. Please reconsider.

Comment: The documentation states: "A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification." - and also documents that `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when the collection is structurally modified.

Comment: But the value is being modified here anyway. Wont that affect the consistency and the point of fail-fast behavior of 'Arraylist'?

Comment: It depends on what's meant by consistency, really. But basically, that's the way it is, and it's behaving exactly as documented. I wouldn't worry too much about why that particular design decision was made - alternatives could easily have been made.

Comment: By consistency, I mean for the same reason modcount is being maintained. Another thread might access the list while the set is being called by another thread. That leads to inconsistent data. I wonder why its not taken in to account.

Comment: Well `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe anyway, in that even if `set` had been called before iterating, the new value might not be seen - likewise if `get` is called without iteration, the new value may or may not be seen.

Comment: Thanx Jon, I think I should focus on other things leaving it being aware that java isn't perfect